# Sql Server :- XML parsing: line 3, character 119, equal expected. Why?

Tags: sql-server-2008

Need help in below XML issue.

```
Create table #temp
( NAME VARCHAR(MAX)
)

Insert Into #temp 

select

 

    '<div class="form-group form-row"><label class="col-sm-5 control-label">Account Name</label><div class="form-controls"><div class="form-control-static">Bond</div></div></div><div class="form-group form-row"><label class="col-sm-5 control-label">Account Number</label><div class="form-controls"><div class="form-control-static">PQR</div></div></div><div class="form-group">
      <label class="control-label">Specific subject</label>
      <input class="input-text form-control" type="text" name="Specific subject" size="20" value="Money Transfer" DISABLED>
    </div><div class="form-group">
      <label class="control-label mandatory" for="message">Message</label>
      <textarea class="textarea form-control" name="message" id="message" cols="30" rows="3" maxlength="5000" DISABLED REQUIRED> The Name is XYZ </textarea><span class="mand">*</span><span class="help-text">Max. 5000 characters</span>
    </div>'

select convert(XML, NAME) from #temp
```

and whenever I am converting the column to XML using

```
convert(XML, Name)
```

it is showing me below error

> XML parsing: line 3, character 119, equal expected.

Need help.

Comment: I think it will be expecting `disabled="true"` for this to be properly qualified XML.  You also have a `REQUIRED` attribute without a value. (HTML is not true HTML).

Comment: @paul  there are so many disabled. Which disabled text which u are referring?

Comment: You're using a `DISABLED` attribute without a value: `<input class="input-text form-control" type="text" name="Specific subject" size="20" value="Money Transfer" DISABLED>`.  Remember HTML is *not* XML - things have to be properly qualified.

Comment: Also Can you please make the changes in script so that I can refer this for the column. @Paul

Comment: What do you mean?  Like this: `<input class="input-text form-control" type="text" name="Specific subject" size="20" value="Money Transfer" disabled="true">`?

Comment: @paul I have very less idea on XML. there is data provided in the column of a table. Using that column I need to extract data from XML tags. but I am not able to convert it as there is a error in the script.

Comment: There's no error in the script; it's an error in the data itself.  See my answer.

Comment: https://www.w3.org/XML/

Answer (score 1):

XML requires fully qualified elements, unlike HTML.

So, your code...

```
Create table #temp
( NAME VARCHAR(MAX)
)

Insert Into #temp 

select

 

    '<div class="form-group form-row"><label class="col-sm-5 control-label">Account Name</label><div class="form-controls"><div class="form-control-static">Bond</div></div></div><div class="form-group form-row"><label class="col-sm-5 control-label">Account Number</label><div class="form-controls"><div class="form-control-static">PQR</div></div></div><div class="form-group">
      <label class="control-label">Specific subject</label>
      <input class="input-text form-control" type="text" name="Specific subject" size="20" value="Money Transfer" DISABLED>
    </div><div class="form-group">
      <label class="control-label mandatory" for="message">Message</label>
      <textarea class="textarea form-control" name="message" id="message" cols="30" rows="3" maxlength="5000" DISABLED REQUIRED> The Name is XYZ </textarea><span class="mand">*</span><span class="help-text">Max. 5000 characters</span>
    </div>'

select convert(XML, NAME) from #temp
```

May only work if you specify values for the assumed Boolean types of `DISABLED` and `REQUIRED`...

```
Create table #temp
( NAME VARCHAR(MAX)
)

Insert Into #temp 

select

 

    '<div class="form-group form-row">
        <label class="col-sm-5 control-label">Account Name</label>
        <div class="form-controls"><div class="form-control-static">Bond</div></div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group form-row">
        <label class="col-sm-5 control-label">Account Number</label>
        <div class="form-controls"><div class="form-control-static">PQR</div></div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="control-label">Specific subject</label>
      <input class="input-text form-control" type="text" name="Specific subject" size="20" value="Money Transfer" disabled="true">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label mandatory" for="message">Message</label>
        <textarea class="textarea form-control" name="message" id="message" cols="30" rows="3" maxlength="5000" disabled="true" required="true"> The Name is XYZ </textarea>
        <span class="mand">*</span>
        <span class="help-text">Max. 5000 characters</span>
    </div>'

select convert(XML, NAME) from #temp
```

I have only picked out the obvious differences, however. I would recommend that you sanitise your data completely, if you are going to process it with SQL.

Comment: New Error is coming :- line 4, character 10, end tag does not match start tag

Comment: @GauravKumar - So that suggests that the data is still wrong.  Check out and cleanse your data first - I cannot do that for you.  The data provided are basically slices of web-pages and, as stated, HTML **is not XML**.

Comment: @GauravKumar - After checking, your `input` tags are not closed - they will need to be closed.